# Grep by character instead on line?

Tags: linux, grep, character, line

I'm working with a nexus file (genomic sequence data) and am unable to convert it to a different format of file. I am suspicious that there is a wacky symbol somewhere in the file that is throwing the conversion off. The file is enormous and I would like to use something like grep to show me if there is a character other than 'A', 'C', 'T', 'G', or '-'. The problem I am running into is that I need to search by character rather than line. If and when I identify a character that does not belong, I then need to know what line of the file it occurs on.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
grep -e A -e T -e C -e G -e '-' -v myfile
```

From my web searching and manual searching I have found that there are various ways to specify the "or" (above I have simply separated them with -e - I am aware there are many ways to do this.) I've also found that -v is for invert-match which is very useful.

What I have been unable to find is how to perform grep by character instead of by line. Perhaps I need a different command? Any help is greatly appreciated.

My file has a few lines of headers and then proceeds in the format of:

```
Strain/sample_name (eg. SRS218000)
Sequence (eg. ACTTTGCCCAGGGG----ATTTTCCGTC----TCGTA-TAAAAATGCT ..... on for millions of characters)
Strain/sample_name (eg. SRS218001)
Sequence (eg. ACTTTGCCCAGGGG----ATTTTCCGTC----TCGTA-TAAAAATGCT ..... on for millions of characters)
Strain/sample_name (eg. SRS218002)
Sequence (eg. ACTTTGCCCAGGGG----ATTTTCCGTC----TCGTA-TAAAAATGCT ..... on for millions of characters)
```

...on for hundreds of samples.

Comment: **Debugging Tip:** It would be a good idea to run the file through `dos2unix` utility to make sure it does not contain `^M` characters.

Comment: Someone suggested: "grep -n -e '[^ACTG-]' filname " and this worked as well! I'm not sure if I accidentally deleted it or what, but I can no longer find it.

Comment: Thats fine. Whatever works! `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use regex in grep. Also to that, output only the differences found, and the line where it occurred.

```
grep -Eno "[^ATCG-]" wheretosearch.txt > outputfile.txt
```

as seen in [grep man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep):

> -E, --extended-regexp
>           Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (see below).
>
> -n, --line-number
>           Prefix each line of output with the line number within its input
>           file.
>
> -o, --only-matching
>           Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.